# angularjs-slider Values without commas

Tags: angularjs, slider, angularjs-slider

The [angularjs-slider](https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider) should display values without commans, and only on the min max values display comma values.
Example: [6.5, 7, 8, .... , 31, 31.5]

If I set

```
$scope.slider = {
  value: 31.5,
  options: {
    floor: 6.5,
    ceil: 31.5,
    step: 1,
    precision: 1
  }
};
```

the values are [6.5, 7.5, 8.5 ... 31.5]

How can I set this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:  i have to set the `stepsArray` option, with the values I want to select.

Example:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp', ['rzModule']);

myApp.controller('TestController', TestController);

function TestController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.priceSlider = {
        value: 31.5,
        options: {
            floor: 6.5,
            ceil: 31.5,
            step: 1,
            precision: 1,
            stepsArray: [6.5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 31.5]
        }
    }
}
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/w3ve98eL/1/